# Phonegap Android App Links not working?

Tags: jquery, android, cordova, dreamweaver

Some links within my Android Phonegap application will work in portrait orientation, but not in landscape orientation. The links are jquery event binded:

```
$('a.button').bind('click',function(){
           //do stuff
           return false;
});
```

Testing within a web browser is 100% fine. Only on the device do the links actually die (in landscape mode). Is it possible that if there are too many objects in the DOM, the Phonegap application starts bugging out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. do you use `pageinit` event before the binding to make sure everything in the dom exists? this is phonegap bestpractice and may help
2. you can try to replace `bind` with .`live` or .`delegate`.  if the links are somehow created with ajax or added to the dom dynamicaly then bind wouldn't work.

Comment: I bind the links after I create them, so it can't be that. Also, the links will work if I simply flip the device into portrait mode. After a lot of testing...this might sound crazy: if the content takes up more space than the device height, the links don't work. However, if the content takes up less, than the links work fine. Is this just with me?